# Spyder installed with Anaconda3 on Ubuntu 16.04: Weird Window Style/Big Menus

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, spyder

I have installed Spyder via Anaconda (Python3/64 Bit) as descibed in the manual on my Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit machine.

But when I start Spyder via:

```
user@computer:~$ anaconda3/bin/spyder
```

the windows and menus look weird as you can see on these screenshots:

[image: window]

[image: menus]

So I thought this comes from files, caches, etc. from remaining installations and deleted them e.g. everything spyder-related that's not within the anaconda3-folder. But still the same result..

Additionally, I created a new user account on the system, signed on and did a fresh install of Anaconda. But it still leads to the same result. So to me it looks as this is an error/bug with Anaconda/Spyder on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have also created an issue here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3671

How can I fix this? Any hints?

Comment: Might this be QT related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discovered that this is a known [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3489) and will be fixed with Spyder version 3.0.2.

Comment: Yep, just came here to say that but you beat me :-)